# Can't get this to compile, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, arrays

OK so I can see the "setUniqueType" on line 33 and the "ItemDetails" on line 50 are what need to be corrected, but I can't figure out what's wrong with it and how to fix it. Please help so I can move in with my program...

**MAIN**

```
package inventory4;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays; 
import javax.swing.JOptionPane; 

public class RunApp
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
   {

  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

  ItemDetails theItem = new ItemDetails();

  int number;
  String Name = "";
  String Type = "";

  String sNumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"How many items are to be put into inventory count?:  ");
  number = Integer.parseInt(sNumber);

  ItemDetails[] inv = new ItemDetails[number];

  for (int count = 0; count < inv.length; ++count)
  {
     Name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"What is item " + (count + 1) + "'s name?");
     theItem.setName(Name);


     Type = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter " + Name + "'s product type");

     theItem.setUniqueType(Type);


     String spNumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter " + Name + "'s product number");
     double pNumber = Double.parseDouble(spNumber);
     theItem.setpNumber(pNumber);

     String sUnits = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"How many " + Name + "s are there in inventory?");

     double Units = Double.parseDouble(sUnits);
     theItem.setUnits(Units);

     String sPrice = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,Name + "'s cost");
     double Price = Double.parseDouble(sPrice);
     theItem.setPrice(Price);


      inv[count] = new ItemDetails(Name, Price, Units, pNumber, Type);
  }



  for (int i = 0; i < inv.length; ++i)
  {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Product Name" + inv[i].getName());

     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Product Type" +  inv[i].getUniqueType());

     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Product Number" + inv[i].getpNumber());

     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Amount of Units in Stock" + inv[i].getUnits());

     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Price per Unit" + inv[i].getPrice());

     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, String.format("Total cost for %s in stock: $%.2f", inv[i].getName(), inv[i].calculateTotalPrice()));

     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,String.format("Restocking fee for %s is $%.2f", inv[i].getName(), inv[i].calculateRestock()));

     String combinedData = inv[i].toString();

     if(i == (inv.length -1)){

        String lastItem = String.format("\nTotal Cost for all items entered: $%.2f\n", Items.getCombinedCost(inv));

        combinedData = combinedData + lastItem; 
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, combinedData);

     }else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, combinedData);
     }


      } //end for


   } //end main


} //end class
```

**ITEMS**

```
package inventory4;


public class Items implements Comparable
{
   private String Name;
   public double pNumber, Units, Price;
   String allInfo;
   public Items()
   {
  Name = "";
  pNumber = 0.0;
  Units = 0.0;
  Price = 0.0;
   }

   public int compareTo(Object item)
   {

      Items tmp = (Items)item;

      return this.getName().compareTo(tmp.getName());
   } // end compareTo method

   public Items(String productName, double productNumber, double unitsInStock, double unitPrice)
   {
  Name = productName;
  pNumber = productNumber;
  Units = unitsInStock;
  Price = unitPrice;
   }

public String toString()
{
   StringBuffer allInfo = new StringBuffer();


   allInfo.append(String.format("Name: %s\n pNumber: %.0f \n Units: %.0f \n Price: %.2f\n",
   getName(),getpNumber(),getUnits(),getPrice()));

   return allInfo.toString();
   }


   //setter methods
   public void setName(String n)
   {
  Name = n;
   }

   public void setpNumber(double no)
   {
      pNumber = no;
   }

   public void setUnits(double u)
   {
      Units = u;
   }

   public void setPrice(double p)
   {
      Price = p;
   }

   //getter methods
   public String getName()
   {
       return Name;
   }

  public double getpNumber()
   {
      return pNumber;
   }

   public double getUnits()
   {
       return Units;
   }

    public double getPrice()
   {
       return Price;
   }

     public double calculateTotalPrice()
   {
       return (Units * Price);
   }

   public static double getCombinedCost(Items[] item) 
   {
  double combined = 0; 

  for (int i = 0; i < item.length; ++i)
  {
     combined = combined + item[i].calculateTotalPrice(); 
  } //end loop

  return combined;
   } //end method

} //end class
```

**ITEM DETAILS**

```
package inventory4;

public class ItemDetails extends Items
 {
    private String UniqueType;

    public ItemDetails()
 {
     super();
 }

public String enterUniqueType()
{
    return UniqueType;
}

public String getUniqueType()
{
      return UniqueType;
}

 public double calculateRestock() //setting up to calculate the restocking fee at 5%
    {
       return (Price * .05);
    }
}
```

Comment: when you say there's an error, please post what exactly your `javac` said.

Comment: "Please help so I can move in with my program..." I'm sorry, I know it's late, you're tired and frustrated, and the last thing you need is some jerk (me) on the internet making fun of you, but... I think moving in with programs is a bad idea. It... it never works out...

Comment: Lesson for starters: error messages tell something about the cause of the problem. Usually a lot. When you *understand* the message and thus also the cause, then the solution should speak for itself. Not understanding them doesn't mean that you can ignore them. Please always include any error messages in your questions. This way one can explain the error message in layman terms so that you can learn understanding them and thus also *understand* the cause of the problem and finally see the solution. When you don't understand a Chinese phrase, you also don't omit it when asking for help, do you?

Comment: Class `ItemDetails` doesn't have a method `setUniqueType`.

Comment: Also, `ItemDetails` doesn't have a constructor that takes the arguments `Name, Price, Units, pNumber, Type`.

Comment: Both errors give the "cannot find symbol" message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compile errors:

```
RunApp.java:31: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method setUniqueType(java.lang.String)
location: class ItemDetails
     theItem.setUniqueType(Type);
            ^
RunApp.java:48: cannot find symbol
symbol  : constructor ItemDetails(java.lang.String,double,double,double,java.lan
g.String)
location: class ItemDetails
      inv[count] = new ItemDetails(Name, Price, Units, pNumber, Type);
                   ^
2 errors
```

1. Your ItemDetails class has no setUniqueType method. You should add one.
2. The constructor you're using at :48 is "String, double, double, double, String" but your constructor is really only "String double double double" Either remove `Type` or add a String parameter to the end of your Item constructor, or make an ItemDEtails constructor with the five parameters.
3. Your ItemDetails has no constructor that matches that argument. If you want to chain the constructor, declare it in ItemDetails

Chaining the constructor:

```
public ItemDetails(String productName, double productNumber, double unitsInStock, double unitPrice
    super(productName,productNumber,unitsInStock,unitPrice);
}
```

Comment: @lost I added how to chain the constructor. You're already doing it for the default constructor actually.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding ItemDetails: it looks like your ItemDetails constructor, inherited from Items, takes only 4 args and you're passing it 5.